# How do I adjust the fidelity of a chart control?

Tags: asp.net, sql, windows, charts

This is what the chart currently looks like:

[image]

This is all the data in the database that it is currently using. (please excuse how the headers are not properly aligning here)

```
Id(Key)   Confidence Love   Stress         Date/Time
    193     0   0   0   12/3/2010 11:33:47 PM
    194     55  55  55  12/3/2010 11:34:04 PM
    195     30  40  20  12/3/2010 11:34:11 PM
    196     40  50  30  12/3/2010 11:34:20 PM
    197     50  60  40  12/3/2010 11:34:28 PM
    198     60  70  50  12/3/2010 11:34:45 PM
    199     70  80  60  12/3/2010 11:34:53 PM
    200     80  90  70  12/3/2010 11:34:59 PM
    201     20  3   11  12/3/2010 11:36:42 PM
    202     20  3   11  12/3/2010 11:37:08 PM
    203     76  34  34  12/3/2010 11:37:41 PM
    204     3   4   2   12/4/2010 12:14:15 AM
    205     5   100 8   12/4/2010 12:17:57 AM
    206     77  89  3   12/12/2010 8:08:49 PM
```

This is the SQL statement I have the chart configured too:

> SELECT [ConfidenceLevel], [LoveLevel],
>   [DateTime], [StressLevel] FROM
>   [UserData]

My issue is in cases like this example, the data recorded around 12/4 looses it's fidelity and is un - "see able", it all blends together.

How can I configure the chart so that the last 20 days are always readable on the chart and that they don't blur together?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts, although please be forgiving as it's hard to get to the root of your challenge without a little more context for the data and the purpose of the graph.

First, the data sample itself seems less than adequate. Indeed, it has gaping holes: **no data** from 12/5 to 12/11? With data, it's garbage in, garbage out. From that perspective, one of your challenges would be to start getting more consistent data.

The line graph falsely implies there is data for the 12/5 to 12/11 date range. Was the "Confidence" level on 12/8 *really* 38? Maybe it was 0? Maybe it was 140? The point is, we don't know, yet the ***connected*** line graph (by it's very nature) is faking us into thinking we do know.

Also, if you're going to use a scale of "days", then I don't understand how you can have multiple values for a single day and try to plot all of those? (Maybe that's not what you're doing... .) I would think you would want to take the average of each of the categories grouped by day and have those groupings be your daily data values. And if you don't have data for a day, then refrain from plotting data you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue is with the chart type you selected as compared to the density/sparsity of your data.

this maybe reminds me of a box-and-whisker type chart,

also consider a bubble chart.